# ¿Cuánta gente reenvía la pregunta a terceros?

Tags: discusión

Es más bien una pregunta retórica. Viendo el mensaje que aparece a veces al final de las preguntas para que *"reenvíes"* la pregunta a quién creas que pueda responderla, me preguntaba si existen estadísticas de cuánta gente realmente se molesta en hacer esta difusión para conseguir aumentar la posibilidad de obtener respuesta.

¿Hay estadísticas de cuántas veces son pulsados estos enlaces que hay al final? ¿Se puede establecer una correlación entre preguntas reenviadas y la afluencia de expertos que den respuestas?

Ya digo que es sólo curiosidad. Imagino que lo más normal es que estos enlaces sean ignorados y que se copie directamente la URL desde el navegador, en todo caso.

Por si no queda claro, me refiero a este mensaje que aparece al final de las preguntas:

---

[image: Compartir pregunta]

---

Comment: Vos estas hablando de el enlace que se ofrece al apretar el boton compartir?

Comment: Para esto habría que hablar con el CM Nicolas para ver si guardan estadísticas de esto.

Comment: @gbianchi No lo llamaría botón. He añadido una imagen del aspecto que tiene.

Comment: Hay una medalla relacionada con cuántas veces se lee un enlace que uno ha compartido.

Comment: Veo que es un texto que solo sale en preguntas con algún tiempo y sin respuestas ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/297401/83)). El enlace que proporciona es del tipo `es.stackoverflow.com/q/297401/83?stw=2`, es decir añade `stw=2` para twitter, sfb para Facebook, etcétera. [Lista aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142535/209901). Sin embargo, no parece que estos datos se guarden en SEDE, por lo que como decía ayer la cantidad de visitas que se reciben así es algo que habría que consultar con un CM.

Comment: Sinceramente yo no lo uso, prefiero copiar y pegar la liga desde la barra superior del navegador, tenga o on respuestas la pregunta que considero interesante.